# Поиск и взятие по маске один и более раз

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Требуется взять все то, что находится между `(" "::"` и между `"::" ")`

Пример:

```
текст текст (var1::var) текст текст (var2::var) текст текст
```

В этом случае `var1 var` и `var2 var`.

Так же, искомый текст может содержать любые символы

Comment: 1. [Медленно](https://regex101.com/r/XV4OE6/1) 2. [Быстро](https://regex101.com/r/PdFqEP/1)

Comment: Зря Вы думаете, что **1.** - это медленно. Я писал ответ на другой вопрос и решил заморочиться замерами производительности регулярных выражений. Потом оказалось, что ТС указал неправильное исходное регулярное выражение и ответ я не опубликовал, но теперь уверенно могу сказать, что 1. [Быстро](https://regex101.com/r/XV4OE6/2) [Ещё быстрее](https://regex101.com/r/XV4OE6/3)  Не смотрите особо на примерное время, указанное regex101. В реальных тестах будут другие показания.

Comment: @ReinRaus, у меня у одного не работает выражение ["еще быстрее"](https://regex101.com/r/XV4OE6/3)?)

Comment: @ReinRaus я не о времени, а о количестве шагов _(итераций в regex-шаблоне)_. В первом варианте моего комментария шагов больше чем во втором почти в два раза.

Comment: Ошибся с копипастой :( https://regex101.com/r/XV4OE6/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$text = 'Пример: текст текст (var1::var) текст текст (var2::var) текст текст';

preg_match_all("#\((.*)::(.*)\)#Uu", $text, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);

var_dump($out);
```